# How to change elements perspective based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d, css-transforms

I was wondering how to replicate [this effect](https://www.pixijs.com/gallery), where the element you are hovering over seems to rotate away from the mouse.

I have worked out how to use css transforms to change an element in 3d space like this:

```css
.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 40px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="card" style="transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(10deg) rotatex(10deg);"></div>
</div>
```

But I'm not sure how to use javascript to make it update based on the mouse position.

Comment: This might be a good tutorial for what you're looking for: https://technokami.in/3d-hover-effect-using-javascript-animations-css-html

Answer (score 2):

This isn't something I'm super familiar with, but looking through the page's source files, it looks like this is the relevant javascript for that functionality:

```js
    bpc.galleryThumbInteraction = function() {
        if (bpc.clickType !== 'tap') {
            TweenMax.set($('.project-list .project'), {rotationY: 0, rotationX: 0, rotationZ: 0, transformPerspective: 1000});
            $('.project-list .project').mouseover(function() {
                $('.project-list .project').mousemove(function(e) {
                    var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
                    y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

                    var px = x/$(this).width(), py = y/$(this).height();
                    var xx = -10 + (20*px), yy = 10 - (20*py);
                    
                    //TweenMax.killTweensOf($(this));
                    TweenMax.to($(this), 0.5, {rotationY: xx, rotationX: yy, rotationZ: 0, transformPerspective: 1000, ease: Quad.easeOut});
                });
            }).mouseout(function() {
                $(this).unbind('mousemove');
                //TweenMax.killTweensOf($(this));
                TweenMax.to($(this), 0.5, {rotationY: 0, rotationX: 0, rotationZ: 0, transformPerspective: 1000, ease: Quad.easeOut});
            });
        }
    };
```

Remember you can often view a pages source files by opening Chrome Dev Tools --> Source Tab --> look for the file you're looking for (in this case, pixi.js)

Also be aware that they are using the [matrix3d()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix3d) css function, which is a bit different than what you have..

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what i'm looking for (since it uses jQuery) but I should be able to work from here!

Answer (score 0):

This particular site uses a library called TweenMax for this effect, here's a more generic function to mimic that effect on any element

```
    function hoverElement3d(className) {
    let selector = '.' + className;
    TweenMax.set($(selector), { rotationY: 0, rotationX: 0, rotationZ: 0, transformPerspective: 1000 });
    $(selector).mouseover(function () {
        $(selector).mousemove(function (e) {
            var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
                y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

            var px = x / $(this).width(), py = y / $(this).height();
            var xx = -10 + (20 * px), yy = 10 - (20 * py);

            TweenMax.to($(this), 0.5, { rotationY: xx, rotationX: yy, rotationZ: 0, transformPerspective: 1000, ease: Quad.easeOut });
        });
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).unbind('mousemove');
        TweenMax.to($(this), 0.5, { rotationY: 0, rotationX: 0, rotationZ: 0, transformPerspective: 1000, ease: Quad.easeOut });
    });
};
```

Keep in min you need both jQuery and [TweenMax 1.18.0](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js) for this exact function to work propely